# How to block movement of tr in jquery sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to sort my table. see my structure

```
<table id="sortable">
    <tr class="not">
        <td>Elements</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

my jquery is

```
<script>
jQuery('#sortable tbody').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {  },
    cancel: '.not',
});
</script>
```

Here I can move the

```
    <tr>
    <td>I am first</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>I am second</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>I am third</td>
</tr>
```

rows to before

```
<tr class="not"><td>Elements</td></tr>
```

How can I block that movement ?

Comment: <script>
      jQuery('#sortable tbody:not(".not")').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {


        }


    });
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to block only the first element, if it is a heading of the table put a `<thead>` tag

see example

```
<table id="sortable">
      <thead>
            <tr class="not"><td>Elements</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <tr><td>I am first</td></tr>
            <tr><td>I am second</td></tr>
            <tr><td>I am third</td></tr>
      </tbody>
</table>

<script>
jQuery('#sortable tbody').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {  }        
});
</script>
```

See demo :http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumarthekkoot/7hhza/

Comment: This one is actually I am looking for Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try comparing the `offset.top` value of `.not` and `sortable` element in the `sort or stop` function. Based on the result of comparison, you can cancel/allow the sort:

JS Code:

```
jQuery('#sortable tbody').sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {},
        cancel: '.not',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var p = $('.not').offset().top;
            var P = ui.position.top;
            if (P < p) {                
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table id="sortable">
    <tr>
        <td>Elements</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am first</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="not">
        <td>I am second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am third</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/155/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[item option](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items)** to exclude specific items. like this:

```
jQuery('#sortable tbody').sortable({
   items: 'tr:not(.not)'
});
```

Comment: I know this code this is used to exclude a <tr> but what I need is I don't want to move another <tr> top of the excluded <tr>

Comment: You can get the drop position in drop event and if its first then revert the drop action.